# Правки prod версии Angular 2 папки dist

Tags: angular2

Мне необходимо править *App*, которое написано на *Angular 2*.

Есть ли возможность, перекомпилировать `.js` - файлы, которые остались после deploy'я *App* на сервер, или нужно править скомпилированные `.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно править `.ts` а потом компилировать  в `js` файлы.
Команды, которыми выполняются компиляция  `ng build` и для деплоя `ng build --prod`, перед этим необходимо установить [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

Если возникла ситуация, что у Вас приложение написано на ES5, то по-умолчанию ничего не нужно компилировать.

Ну, а если вы решили просто править уже скомпилированное приложение, то лучше этого никогда не делать или в самом крайнем случае (когда исходником нет и нужно что то поправить), хотя даже это не отговорка. Правка в `dist` может привести к таким последствиям:
1 При изменении кода проекте (typescript ) Ваши правки dist пропадут;
2 код может не работать. (Вы на проде поправили и он возникла ошибка);
3 ну и самое опасное это то, что ошибку можно не заметить сразу и она всплывёт потом.

Comment: Спасибо, везде где читал, написано загружать на сервер только папку dist, я так понял, что папка src тоже должна быть, для правок готового проекта?

Comment: Вообще, я проект выливаю весь на прод. И на проде уже есть npm, cli и gulp. Запускаю gulp команду для билда приложения

Comment: По этому если Вы выливате папку src, тогда выливайте уже весь проект. Протому что просто одна папка src не поможет.

Comment: Спасибо Константин